# what is the best way to validate password and confirm password in grails?

Tags: grails

I have a Domain class that contains password & password_confirm fields.
These two get validated separately.
What is the best practice to create a validation that these two are equal?

Answer (score 4):

```
class User {

  String password
  String passwordConfirm


  static constraints = {
    password blank: false, nullable: false, minSize: 8, maxSize: 64, validator: {password, obj ->
      def password2 = obj.passwordConfirm
      password2 == password ? true : ['invalid.matchingpasswords']
    }
  }

}
```

Then add the following to your messages.properties file...

```
User.password.invalid.matchingpasswords=Passwords do not match
```

When user.save() or user.validate() is called, this will trigger automatically.

Comment: Validation is ok, and I also add `password` and `passwordConfirm` to [transients](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html), otherwise they will be persisted. Another option is to use a CommandObject for validation.

Comment: Why would you add password to transients?  You should be storing the password.  Just not the passwordConfirm.

Comment: For security reasons I would save the hash generated by the password in a different field, for example `passwordHash`.

Comment: How is that more secure?  Just because it isn't a common name?

Comment: To sum up, I'd use three fields: `password` and `passwordConfirm` for validation and  `passwordHash` to save the generated hash. The first two should be available only one request, so they would be transients.

Comment: This isn't working for me, which is why I am here.  In my case obj is null and I am not sure how to address this because I don't know how the form being built is wired in in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a security plugin for Grails, maybe Shiro or Spring Security Core.

In the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/12%20Password%20and%20Account%20Protection.html#12.3%20Account%20Locking%20and%20Forcing%20Password%20Change) of Spring Security Core there's a example of changing the password:

```
def updatePassword = {
   String username = session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']
   if (!username) {
      flash.message = 'Sorry, an error has occurred'
      redirect controller: 'login', action: 'auth'
      return
   }
   String password = params.password
   String newPassword = params.password_new
   String newPassword2 = params.password_new_2
   if (!password || !newPassword || !newPassword2 || newPassword != newPassword2) {
      flash.message = 'Please enter your current password and a valid new password'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }

   User user = User.findByUsername(username)
   if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, password, null /*salt*/)) {
      flash.message = 'Current password is incorrect'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }

   if (passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, newPassword, null /*salt*/)) {
      flash.message = 'Please choose a different password from your current one'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }

   user.password = newPassword
   user.passwordExpired = false
   user.save() // if you have password constraints check them here

   redirect controller: 'login', action: 'auth'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.so I don't need to use command object for validation?

Comment: It's recommended to use a command object. You can adapt this code to a [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

Comment: Suppose I have User domain class and UserCommand class. 
So when user is registering on website there are two steps for data validation:

UserCommand constraints validation.
User domain object constrains validation.
How Can I pass both of those class to controller action and view?